# ASP.Net MVC: Request.IsAuthenticated getting false after successfully login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am using asp.net MVC and identity to authenticate user. i saw after successfully authenticate `Request.IsAuthenticated return false`

this is sample login code which i debug and saw it is working fine.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

after successfully login page redirect to home index action where i am showing user information in index view like below way but controls never come there because of `Request.IsAuthenticated return false`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @{
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                <p>@currentUser.UserName</p>
                <p>@currentUser.BirthDate</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>not authenticated</p>
            }
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

just do not understand what i am missing for which request authenticate method always returning false. please help me to fix it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running the application with IISExpress under HTTP. After I switched to HTTPS by setting SSL Enabled to true in the project properties the problem was solved.